# Checking battery saving mode in kitkat 4.4

Tags: android, battery, android-4.4-kitkat, battery-saver

There is a battery saving mode in Android KitKat 4.4. It will optimize the GPS and other features to save battery life. Is it possible to check whether ones phone is in battery saving mode ?

Comment: What battery save mode? Could you be talking about Samsung-specific features? Google's stock KitKat has no such thing.

Comment: @ChenAsraf, AFAIK, the OP is talking about the "Location mode" settings. There, one of the three options, is "Battery saving".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should help, please note that this is available only on API level 19+:

```
private void checkLocationModeSettings() {
    int mode = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE,
            Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF);

    switch (mode) {
        case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY:
            Log.d(TAG, "Sensor only mode");
            break;
        case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING:
            Log.d(TAG, "Battery saving mode");
            break;
        case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY:
            Log.d(TAG, "High accuracy mode");
            break;
        case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF:
        default:
            Log.d(TAG, "Location access is disabled");
    }
}
```